AWS IoT Sensor Payload to Timestream multiple measure values
We have setup IoT sensor data which is getting inserted to Timestream using AWS Rules. The issue is we want to have a multiple measure values/names in a row instead of each attribute consuming a separate row.
Tthe sensor JSON payload looks like this:
{
  "device_id": "124710xxxx",
  "temperature": 26.3,
  "humidity": 66.5,
  "pir": "idle",
  "light_level": 0,
  "co2": 731,
  "tvoc": 1,
  "pressure": 1012.7,
  "hcho": 0.02,
  "pm2_5": 62,
  "pm10": 78
}

Could you please suggest a solution?
AWS Rule > Timestream
